# How to make material ui sidebar to open the main content in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, sidebar

I am a newbie to react and currently developing an application,

**BACKGROUND**

It has admin, faculty, student, dashboards.amd a static landing page with buttons to go to /admin/login ,/faculty/login ,/student/login. which opens respective dashboards  [![Once admin logins he gets this dashboard page ][1]][1]

**PROBLEM:**

***App.js***

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./routes";
import firebase from "./Firebase";

const App = props => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes {...props} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  ReactDOM.render(<App user={user} />, document.getElementById("root"));
});
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import MainLayout from "./OtherComponents/Common/MainLayout";
//Home
import Home from "./MainComponents/Home";
import HomePublicRoute from "./OtherComponents/Routes/Home/HomePublicRoute";
//ADMIN
//components
import AdminLogin from "./OtherComponents/Login/Admin";

import AdminDash from "./MainComponents/Admin";
import AdminPublicRoute from "./OtherComponents/Routes/Admin/AdminPublicRoutes";
import AdminPrivateRoute fro"./OtherComponents/Routes/Admin/AdminPrivateRoutes";
//pages
import PageDashboard from "./MainComponents/Admin/pages/dashboard";
import AdminTaluka from "./MainComponents/Admin/pages/taluka";


const Routes = props => {
  console.log(props);

  return (
    <MainLayout>
      <Switch>
        <AdminPublicRoute
          {...props}
          exact
          restricted={true}
          path="/admin/login"
          component={AdminLogin}
        />
        <AdminPrivateRoute
          {...props}
          path="/admin/admindashboard"
          exact
          component={AdminDash}
        />


       <AdminPrivateRoute
              {...props}
              path="/admin/pagedashboard"
              exact
              component={PageDashboard}
            />



        <AdminPrivateRoute
          {...props}
          path="/admin/taluka"
          exact
          component={AdminTaluka}
        />

        <HomePublicRoute path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
    </MainLayout>
  );
};
export default Routes;
```

***MainLayout.js***

```
import React from "react";
//var reactRouterToArray = require("react-router-to-array");
const MainLayout = props => {
  //console.log(reactRouterToArray(props.children));
  return <div>{props.children}</div>;
};
export default MainLayout;
```

- Sidebar doesn't open the content inside the main container instead it opens in a new tab if i use route inside routes.js .
- Sidebar doesn't open the content if i use route inside AdminDash.js .
- i have tried passing the routes using props (props.children) to AdminDash( its not receivng the prop)
- I am using private and public routes.

I am confused and I don't know where am I going wrong any suggetions , or hints would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a screenshot is always better than taken picture by a camera. If you think it is necessary to send the whole project code, create a project in https://codesandbox.io/  or https://codepen.io/

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will take care of that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sidebar doesn't open the content inside the main container instead it opens in a new tab if i use route inside routes.js .

Inside `LeftDrawer` you are rendering links to the content. You should use `react-router-dom` [Link elements](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md).

Like this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

<Link to="/about">About</Link>
```

> Sidebar doesn't open the content if i use route inside AdminDash.js .

Routes shouldn't be defined multiple times. You have defined `/admin/pagedashboard` both in AdminDash.js and Routes.js. If you want to have a shared shell around the content, define routes inside the shell component and remove exact route from the parent routes.

Example:

```
MainLayout
.Routes
../admin
...AdminDash (Shell for multiple pages, admin layout)
..../admindashboard
.....AdminDasboard
..../pagedashboard
.....PageDashboard
```

> i have tried passing the routes using props (props.children) to AdminDash( its not receivng the prop)

You should just import them when needed.

**EDIT:**

Remove exact from the Routes.js `<Route path='/admin' component={AdminDash} />` and in AdminDash try

```
const AdminDash = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <Route path={${match.url}/admindashboard} component={AdminContent}/>
    <Route path={${match.url}/pagedashboard} component={PageContent}/>
  </div>
);
```

In the above example take note to change `AdminContent` and `PageContent` with the names of your components.

Comment: Actually, i have the links which are stored as an array inside admin data file which i am importing inside the AdminDash file, My bad ( i have included it just now in the question) . AdminDash is currently supposed to work as shell component but its not working , route  /admin/pagedashboard is in route.js but i have tried coomenting it in the routes.js instead inAdminDash but no luck

Comment: Remove `exact` from the Routes.js `<Route path='/admin' component={AdminDash} />` and in AdminDash try

`const AdminDash = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/admindashboard`} component={AdminContent}/>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/pagedashboard`} component={PageContent}/>
  </div>
) `

Comment: When the example with `Route` component gets working, then add your proprietary route components

Comment: yeah, ill try that

Comment: Thanks, passing this.props to admin dash and creating its as shell component worked.